# How to check push provisioning api access (package white listed or not) or not for android

Tags: android, provisioning, google-provisioning-api, android-tap-and-pay

How to check push provisioning api access (package white listed or not) or not for android.

I have fill the form given URL https://support.google.com/faqs/contact/pp_api_allowlist

But I need to check its app white listed or not. How I can check?

because its giving error 15009 package not verified.

Please help for the same,

Thank You

Can I check app is whitelisted or not for push provisioning.